# How to convert date string to time_t

Tags: c++

I am trying to convert "Tue Feb 13 00:26:36 2018" to `time_t`, how can I do this, I tried looking for a function and couldn't find it. This is using unmanaged C++.

Comment: Take a look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time or http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time

Comment: possible duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213326/how-to-convert-a-string-variable-containing-time-to-time-t-type-in-c and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11218797/convert-date-and-time-numbers-to-time-t-and-specify-the-timezone

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a string variable containing time to time\_t type in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213326/how-to-convert-a-string-variable-containing-time-to-time-t-type-in-c)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using C++11, you can do it like this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    struct tm tm;
    std::istringstream iss("Tue Feb 13 00:26:36 2018");
    iss >> std::get_time(&tm, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y");
    time_t time = mktime(&tm);

    std::cout << time << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```