# Date/Time into time_t in C

Tags: c, time

I am trying to calculate the time, in seconds, for a certain timestamp. How can I input a date and time into time_t so I can calculate the time from time(null)? (time(null) is 01/01/1970 if I understand it right)

Comment: If you're lucky your platform has a [`strptime`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strptime.html) function.

Comment: The usual way is to fill in an instance of `struct tm`, then call [`mktime()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/mktime).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Date/time conversion: string representation to time\_t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321793/date-time-conversion-string-representation-to-time-t)

Comment: [How to convert a string variable containing time to time_t type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11213326/995714), [Converting a Datetime String to Epoch Cleanly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/856551/995714), [How to convert date string to time_t](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48800745/995714)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example that computes the time more or less now, where I am:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    time_t t;
    struct tm tm;

    /* fill in values for 2019-08-22 23:22:26 */
    tm.tm_year = 2019 - 1900;
    tm.tm_mon = 8 - 1;
    tm.tm_mday = 22;
    tm.tm_hour = 23;
    tm.tm_min = 22;
    tm.tm_sec = 26;
    tm.tm_isdst = -1;
    t = mktime(&tm);
    printf("%ld\n", t);
}
```

As you can see, the values in some of the fields use mildly strange conventions: `tm_mon` is 0-based, and `tm_year` counts from 1900.  Setting `tm_isdst` to -1 means "I'm not sure if DST applied on August 22; you figure it out".

When I run it, this program prints 1566530546, which is indeed the number of seconds since midnight UTC on January 1, 1970.  (If you run the program, though, you'll likely get a slightly different number, because it will work from 23:22:26 in your time zone.)

As the preceding paragraphs suggest, the `mktime` function does take your time zone into account, as well as any necessary DST correction.  If you want to do a similar conversion without these corrections, there's an analogous function called `timegm`, although it's not Standard and not present on all systems.

The `tm_wday` and `tm_yday` (day of week and day of year) fields are ignored when you call `mktime`, although they will have been filled in with their correct values when the function returns.

Comment: As `struct tm` may have other members then the usual 9, best to initialize all members with  `struct tm tm = { 0 };` to have consistent results from `mktime(&tm)`.

Comment: Thanks! this helped. I am pretty knew to C so I think some of the Documentation I read talked about structures but this cleared that up.

Comment: mktime() calculates the seconds of epoch to the current timezone. I needed to use timegm() to completely solve the issue because the timezone of the input data is also UTC.